# * selector works in getElementsByTagName(), but not for getElementsByClassName() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I can use '*' selector in getElementsByTags(), but not in getElementsByClassName() or getElementByID().

Could someone explain why? And, is there anyway to use substring selector in javascript methods ie (getElementsByClassName("*profile") to select elements whose class name includes 'profile'?

The below is my code:

```
<body>
<div class="yahoo">
</div>
<p class="yahoo">
</p>
<ul class="yahoo">
</ul>

<div class="yahoo">
</div>


<input type='text'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function select(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*")
    var elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("*")
    console.log(elements)
}

select()
</script>
```

Comment: _“Could someone explain why?”_ – because `*` _by definition_ means “any possible element name”, and not “any possible class name”.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior conforms with DOM-Level-2-Core [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1938918D) which states that:

> **getElementsByTagName**
>     Returns a NodeList of all descendant Elements with a given tag name, in the order in which they are encountered in a preorder traversal of this Element tree.
>     *Parameters*
>   **name** of type DOMString
>   The name of the tag to match on. The special value "*" matches all tags.

There is no special notion for chracter `*` for `getElementsByClassName` method, which is treated literally as class name.

**UPD**. Addressing your second question:

> is there anyway to use substring selector in javascript methods ie (getElementsByClassName("*profile") to select elements whose class name includes 'profile'?

You can't use `getElementsByClassName` however it's possible to use another very useful `querySelectorAll` method for this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class*="profile"]');
```

Comment: You and I addressed different parts of the same question (both of us, I imagine, aiming to answer the *other* part in edits); if you wanted to incorporate my answer into yours (for a single clean solution) I'd appreciate it; then I can delete my answer and leave one *complete* solution.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thank you for pointing it out, I indeed missed second part! But there is no need for you to remove yours answer, it have useful links and explanation.